# APIs for implementing Document Editing and viewing features for a web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, content-management-system, zoho

I'm looking for APIs to bring online document editing features for a web app - Any suggestions? The criteria of selection depends on the following factors

- Support for editing for common document formats (doc, docx)
- Support for viewing common document and presentation formats (doc, docx, pdf, ppt, pptx)
- The API should be easily accessible from ASP.NET environment
- We are not looking for data hosting - The data/documents will be kept in the local repository. The API/Related framework should have some functionality to load the documents from a store, provide a UI to the user to edit them, and save them back to the store
- The editor/view component should be able to keep track of user annotations on a specific part of document etc

One option I'm evaluating is Zoho Remote API - http://apihelp.wiki.zoho.com/Zoho-API-Program---Overview.html

What I Would like to know

- Any similar APIs (Suggestions, links etc)
- Any experience you have (issues, problems) with Zoho API in ASP.NET
- Normal challenges in integrating document editing/viewing in web apps

Comment: I am still looking a webapi for editing docx on browser, do you came across any?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered [Google Docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/documents/)?

Comment: Do they have an API so that I can embed those features?

Comment: Not sure if this will allow you to "embed" the editing features within your web application, however I'm sure you can find a nice way to integrate.